# Splitting groupby results for subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, `stock_data.head()`:

```
       date     open    high    low     close    volume    Name
0   2013-02-08  15.07   15.12   14.63   14.75   8407500     AAL
1   2013-02-11  14.89   15.01   14.26   14.46   8882000     AAL
2   2013-02-12  14.45   14.51   14.10   14.27   8126000     AAL
3   2013-02-13  14.30   14.94   14.25   14.66   10259500    AAL
4   2013-02-14  14.94   14.96   13.16   13.99   31879900    AAL
```

Below I have a code for producing a `groupby` command from my dataframe:

```
avg_permonth = stock_data.set_index('date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
avg_permonth['volume'].mean()


date
2013-02-28    5.261789e+06
2013-03-31    4.825485e+06
2013-04-30    4.990292e+06
2013-05-31    4.836257e+06
2013-06-30    5.145598e+06
                  ...     
2017-10-31    3.903486e+06
2017-11-30    4.133801e+06
2017-12-31    3.919748e+06
2018-01-31    4.486669e+06
2018-02-28    6.249305e+06
Freq: M, Name: volume, Length: 61, dtype: float64
```

My question is, how can I split these results by year to then create subplots of `date vs volume`? (would I have to `reset_index()` first or can I plot the `index` as `x axis`?) I wish the for 5 `subplots` from `2013-02` to `2018-02`.

I tried with this [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606524/how-to-make-an-axes-occupy-multiple-subplots-when-using-pandas-datetime-plot) but did not give the outcome I was looking for - it was 5 subplots but the `x axis` was from 2013 - 2018 for each plot and all had the same plot.

I wish for the `x axis` on the first subplot to be from the first date value of 2013 to the last date value of 2013, the second plot for 2014 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dummy values like your serie
s = pd.Series(range(12*6), 
              index=pd.date_range('2013-01-01', '2018-12-31', freq='M'), 
              name='volume')

# Create figure and axs for multiple Axes
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(12,12))

# groupby year to plot each year un a subplot
for i, (year, sg) in enumerate(s.groupby(s.index.year)):
    # plot each year in a subplot
    sg.plot(ax=axs[i//2, i%2]) # here you can add several parameters for colors and stuff
    # or axs[i//2, i%2].plot(sg.index, sg.values) would give the same result
plt.show()
```

Comment: This has an issue with the top line of the `for` loop: `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
`.In exchange for your `s.groupby(s.index.year)` I have put my version `avg_permonth.groupby(avg_permonth.index.year)`. Can I not do another `groupby` since it is already done? @Ben.T

Comment: @pragmaticlearner what I called `s` is actually the same structure that `avg_permonth['volume'].mean()` because I understood it is what you wanted to plot this, but if you goal is to plot all the points, then  you can replace `s.groupby(s.index.year)` by `stock_data.set_index('date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y'))['volume']` e.g.