# 4 plots with different sizes on one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I need to create 4 plots, where there are two large ones and two stacked smaller ones to the right (the sum is the same as the large plots). Picture attached.
[image]

So far I managed only to create two separate figures:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 4))
#plotting
fig, axs_right = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(4, 8))
#plotting
```

The difficulty is that I need to plot with seaborn and have control over axes to change the way they look.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265319/how-to-make-an-axes-occupy-multiple-subplots-with-pyplot

Comment: In particular, suggest using subplot_mosaic: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/provisional/mosaic.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a relatively simple layout you can achieve with [`plt.subplot2grid()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid.html):

```
grid = (2, 3)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))  # or whatever

ax = plt.subplot2grid(grid, (0, 0), rowspan=2)  # left column plot
...

ax = plt.subplot2grid(grid, (0, 1), rowspan=2)  # middle column plot
...

ax = plt.subplot2grid(grid, (0, 2))  # right column upper plot
...

ax = plt.subplot2grid(grid, (1, 2))  # right column lower plot
...
```

Result: [image]

Comment: Your code works, but if I add my plotting it still plots two separate figures: one with 2 large plots and one with two small plots

Comment: Then you must be creating a second figure somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving that, it is described in the ["Arranging multiple Axes in a Figure"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/arranging_axes.html#arranging-multiple-axes-in-a-figure) part of the matplotlib documentation.

Below is a basic recopy for your case:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figsize = (7, 4)

# Method 1
fig, axd = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    [
        ["1", "2", "3"],
        ["1", "2", "4"],
    ],
    figsize=figsize,
    layout="constrained",
)


# Method 2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, layout="constrained")
spec = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=3, nrows=2)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[:, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[:, 1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 2])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 2])


# Method 3
fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, layout="constrained")
spec0 = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=2, nrows=1, width_ratios=[2, 1])
spec01 = spec0[0].subgridspec(ncols=2, nrows=1)
spec02 = spec0[1].subgridspec(ncols=1, nrows=2)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec01[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec01[1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec02[0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(spec02[1])

plt.show()
```

[image: subplots layout]