# How do I display multiple matplotlib.pyplot plots in the same figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making three scatter plots, and I'd like them to all show up in the same window (but not in the same plot).  Right now, three separate windows pop up, one for each plot.  If I move `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` outside the loop, then they are all plotted on the same set of axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot

time = [1,2,3]
value = {}
value['x'] = [1,2,3]
value['y'] = [1,4,9]
value['z'] = [1,8,27]
for dimension in ['x', 'y', 'z']:
    matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(time, value[dimension])
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358977/how-to-make-several-plots-on-a-single-page-using-matplotlib

Comment: @cyborg I saw that, but I still couldn't figure out my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `subplot` to create subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time = [1,2,3]
value = {}
value['x'] = [1,2,3]
value['y'] = [1,4,9]
value['z'] = [1,8,27]
for k, dimension in enumerate(['x', 'y', 'z']):
    plt.subplot(3, 1, k)
    plt.scatter(time, value[dimension])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there has been a python version change that breaks the above code, it did not run for me because `enumerate` now starts at `0`, for example `enumerate(iterable, start=0)` is the base case, so I made the following modification and it ran:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time = [1,2,3]
value = {}
value['x'] = [1,2,3]
value['y'] = [1,4,9]
value['z'] = [1,8,27]
for k, dimension in enumerate(['x', 'y', 'z'], 1):
#     print(k, dimension)
    plt.subplot(3, 1, k)
    plt.scatter(time, value[dimension])

plt.show()
```