# Plot two histogram in same window but in different plots

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to plot two different histograms in different plots but opening in same window. With the following code, I am getting two histogram in same plot. I could not get the histogram with subplot don't know where I went wrong.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    img = cv2.imread(f)
    img1 = cv2.imread('compressed_' + f)
    color = ('b', 'g', 'r')
    for i, col in enumerate(color):
        histr = cv2.calcHist([img], [i], None, [256], [0, 256])
        hist = cv2.calcHist([img1], [i], None, [256], [0, 256])
        plt.plot(histr, color=col)
        plt.plot(hist, color=col)
        plt.xlim([0, 256])
        plt.title('Original image')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by _in different graphs_? Different windows? Same window seperate plots?

Comment: Yes same window different plots

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make several plots on a single page using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358977/how-to-make-several-plots-on-a-single-page-using-matplotlib)

Comment: Please look into ```subplot``` from [docs](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot.html)

Comment: I had looked but could not solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to create two subplots. For this you should use the [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) function from matplotlib.

Your code should look something like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(f)
img1 = cv2.imread('compressed_' + f)
color = ('b', 'g', 'r')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)

for i, col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img], [i], None, [256], [0, 256])
    hist = cv2.calcHist([img1], [i], None, [256], [0, 256])
    ax[0].plot(histr, color=col)
    ax[1].plot(hist, color=col)
    plt.xlim([0, 256])
    plt.title('Original image')
plt.show()
```

Comment: ax[0] and ax[1] takes which value? they are unreferenced

Comment: @user162817 Thanks for pointing that out. Added the missing line :)