# How do I plot multiple graphs using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing some EDA on a dataset I have using `seaborn` primarily. However, I'd like to plot these graphs in a single kernel. I think I'm meant to use `matplotlib` to achieve this. I've done 3 separate `sns.countplot` graphs, but I'm trying to show them in one single kernel/output.

I've tried using the following code but I'm still not entirely sure how it works:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(16,8))

ax = sns.countplot(y = 'loan_status', data = df, order = df['loan_status'].value_counts().iloc[:6].index)

ax = sns.countplot(y = 'loan_status', data = df, order = df['loan_status'].value_counts().iloc[2:9].index)

ax = sns.distplot(df['loan_amnt'], bins=50)
```

Comment: Please include minimal code for the plots you are trying to make so that it is easier for posters to test your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make several plots on a single page using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358977/how-to-make-several-plots-on-a-single-page-using-matplotlib)

Comment: Note, if you only want three plots, then you can use `fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(16,8))` or `fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(16,8))` depending on if you'd like them laid out horizontally or vertically, respectively. Again, having the code you'd like to plot would be helpful here.

Comment: sorry for not posting the code, i've just added

Comment: Okay. So, is your code working and you just want to know how it works, or is it not working at all? Did you include a `plt.show()` command?

Comment: Hey Todd,

the code works but it doesn't return three separate graphs. instead, it returns one really incorrect graph. If I run each line separately then they work fine. I'm just trying to get all three graphs in one window

Comment: Change your fig, axes call to `fig, [ax1, ax2, ax3] = plt.subplots(1, 3. figsize(16,8))` and then rename each individual plot with ax1, ax2, ax3. Does that help?

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: If you'ld like to try with Matplotlib, browse throught the [gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#subplots-axes-and-figures) to find the features you want then look at the example code to see how it was accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
fig, [ax1, ax2, ax3] = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(16,8))

     ax1 = sns.countplot(y = 'loan_status', data = df, order = df['loan_status'].value_counts().iloc[:6].index)

     ax2 = sns.countplot(y = 'loan_status', data = df, order = df['loan_status'].value_counts().iloc[2:9].index)

     ax3 = sns.distplot(df['loan_amnt'], bins=50)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: No problem. Please remember to participate in the community by marking the most helpful solution to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some random data to plot
M = np.random.rand(3,100,100)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(16,8))

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    ax.imshow(M[i])

# OR
# axes[0].imshow(M[0])
# axes[1].imshow(M[1])
# axes[2].imshow(M[2])

plt.show()
```