# I am getting an error when trying to plot a matplotlib scatter plot using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am getting an error I cant seem to understand when im trying to plot a scatterplot below:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    plt.scatter(df['polarity'][i], df['subjectivity'][i], color = 'Blue' )

plt.title('Sentiment Analysis')
plt.xlabel('Polarity')
plt.ylabel('Subjectivity')
plt.show()
```

Where my polarity and subjectivity cols are number values

I get

```
KeyError:3  

 ----> 3     plt.scatter(df['polarity'][i], df['subjectivity'][i], color = 'Blue' )
```

not sure what I am missing here, any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45229426/8973620)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make several plots on a single page using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358977/how-to-make-several-plots-on-a-single-page-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['polarity'][i]` extract item at index `i` of the series `df['polarity']`. The error says `df['polarity']` does not have an index `3`, for example, `df` can look like

```
   polarity
0         1
1         2
2         3
4         1
```

Why don't you try:

```
plt.scatter(df['polarity'], df['subjectivity'], color='b')
```

Or:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='polarity', y='subjectivity')
```